# Why does Left Ctrl trigger FocusOut in xev?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

When I press Left Ctrl, my `xev` output shows this:

```
FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5600001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor
```

When I press Right Ctrl, there's no FocusOut event. Why so?

---

**Problem background:**

When I press Enter and then Ctrl+V *really fast*, the Ctrl+V doesn't work (it doesn't paste anything). I narrowed down the problem using `xev`. When I press Enter and then immediately Ctrl+V, the "V" isn't registered by operating system. Instead, it's stuck on Ctrl, displaying the FocusOut event. However, it works alright with *Right Ctrl*.

I thought that Left Ctrl shouldn't trigger FocusOut in the first place, and asked the question.

Comment: Are you using any VM hosts? Its not uncommon for left ctrl or left alt to be an escape key.

Comment: @Linef4ult good idea, but no, VirtualBox isn't launched (although it's installed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out, Left Ctrl was mapped to "Maximize window" :)

Unmap, reboot - and it works perfectly!

Comment: I have the same problem but none of keyboard shortcut I have are mapped to only left `ctrl`.